# Getting information from struct in a different method to where it's set using C#

Tags: c#, methods, struct

So basically my issue is that I have a method in my program that sets the data in a struct for a student which looks like:

```
public static void addingstudent(){
        student student;
        AddStudent details = new AddStudent();
        student.name = details.setName();
        student.course = details.setCourse();
        student.studentno = details.setStudentNumber();
        student.year = details.setYear();
        menu();         
    }
```

The AddStudent class contains a few methods for asking the user to input the Name etc. and returning them, an example in this class would be:

```
public static int setStudentNo(){
    Console.Write("Please enter Student Number: ");
    int StudentNo = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    return StudentNo;
}
```

And then I'm trying to access that data and display it on screen with:

```
public static void getstudent(){
        student student;
        student.displayDetails();
    }
```

Which is just displaying null values for all the variables, however if I call this after first setting the values it displays correctly, lastly the struct looks like:

```
public struct student{

    public String name;
    public int studentno;
    public String course;
    public int year;

    public void displayDetails(){

        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + name);
        Console.WriteLine("Student Number: "+studentno);
        Console.WriteLine("Course: "+course);
        Console.WriteLine("Year: "+year);
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of the AddStudent class as well as the context where you call these methods. The error may lie there. Also, you may want to step through your code with the debugger and check that your assignments are working correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You user `student student` in `addingstudent()` but another `student student` in `getstudent()` as far as I can see... you are not using the same object...

You can have a class which has the struct and the two functions

```
class A
{
     studnet studnet;
     public static void addingstudent()
     {        
        AddStudent details = new AddStudent();
        student.name = details.setName(); 
        student.course = details.setCourse();
        student.studentno = details.setStudentNumber(); 
        student.year = details.setYear();  
        menu(); 
     } 

     public static void getstudent()
     {    
         student.displayDetails(); 
     } 
}
```

Then just create a new A class and manipulate with the data however you want

Comment: That's what I thought I'm wondering how do I get the same object in both methods though, that's my problem now

Comment: This still isn't working for me as it's not letting me using student to add details for example student.name just will not work in the method without calling the struct within the method as well for some reason.

Comment: Is there any special reason why you use struct instead of a class? Just create a student class add some properties and methods and you can do what ever you want

Answer (score 0):

Creating mutable structs is a bad idea in the first place, if the data is mutable you really should create a class.

Also, you are not passing the stuct as a parameter, for example in `getstudent` you are creating a new student object every time, this is why `student.displayDetails();` is showing null, because you have not set any of the properties of the student you created on the line before you call it.

```
    public static void getstudent()
    {
        Student student; // creates a new instance of the struct... 
        student.displayDetails(); // obviously student properties are null...
    }
```

Really you should be doing something like the following.

```
public class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
       this.SetName();
       this.SetNumber();
       this.SetCourse()
       this.SetYear();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format(
                   "Name: {0}{4}Number: {1}{4}Course: {2}{4}Year: {3}{4}",
                    this.Name,
                    this.Number,
                    this.Course,
                    this.Year,
                    Environment.NewLine);
    }

    public void DisplayDetails()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.ToString());
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Number{ get; private set; }
    public string Course { get; private set; }
    public string Year { get; private set; }

    public static void SetName()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Please enter Name: ");
      this.Name = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void SetNumber()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Please enter Number: ");
      this.Number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    public static void SetCourse()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Please enter Course: ");
      this.Course = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void SetYear()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Please enter Year: ");
      this.Year = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}

public class App
{
    public static void Main()
    {
       Student student1 = new Student(); // Create a student
       student1.DisplayDetails(); // show the details 

       student1.SetName(); // change the name
       student1.SetYear(); // change the year
       student1.DisplayDetails(); // show the new details 

       // etc...
    }
}
```